# Use Telegram API to get past messages from a channel without requiring user login

Tags: node.js, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I need to read the latest 20 messages from a telegram channel.
If possible, I would like to use a Telegram bot to read the latest 20 messages.

I'm coding in typescript/node js.

I don't want to log in with my phone. This code will be run in a stateless API, the API will always provide the latest 20 messages to the frontend. But because it's an API I can't maintain a user session by logging in with my phone; instead it should only use the telegram API ID/hash.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This community is not a code writing service that follows your instructions. Please specify a particular problem, show what you have done so far and explain your problem in detail.